# multiple image resizes at once in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a image and resize it, and make a smaller copy of it. But it won't do the second resize. But it returns 'TRUE'.

I found more questions about it, but they did not do the trick, suggestions like:

- Add `$this->image_lib->clear();` before every resize
- Do not load the library every time you resize
- Make your directories writable (777)

I think this is not the problem with my code.

If i'm missing something, please let me know.

```
private function upload_image($id)
{
    $config_1['upload_path'] = './public/img/news/';
    $config_1['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
    $config_1['file_name'] = 'news_item_'.$id.'.jpg';
    $config_1['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config_1['max_size']   = '900';
    $config_1['max_width']  = '5000';
    $config_1['max_height']  = '5000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config_1);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))
    {
        $image_data     =   $this->upload->data();
        $this->load->library('image_lib');

        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $image_data['full_path'];
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['quality']   = 75;
        if($image_data['image_width'] > 2000){
            $config['width']     = 2000;
            $config['height']    = 1500;
        }
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config); 
        if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize()){echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();}
        $this->image_lib->clear();

        //thumb
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $image_data['full_path'];
        $config['new_image']    = './public/img/news/thumb/news_item_'.$id.'.jpg';
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['quality']   = 75;
        $config['width']     = 650;
        $config['height']    = 500;

        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize()){echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();}
        $this->image_lib->clear();
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION**
That was it, damn. The **!** at `if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))` should not be there. It works now Thanks guys!

Comment: Does it work for one resize?

Comment: Yes, the first resize goes well, but when i use 'new image' at the second resize it does nothing

Comment: Try this $this->image_lib->resize();
 After your $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

Comment: But the `$this->image_lib->resize();` is already after the initialize function, what do you mean? @NishantLad

Comment: See i have edited your code

Comment: It still does the same, the only thing changed is that the function resize is called 4 times, instead of once in the if statement. @NishantLad

Comment: And you have also written code of resize in  if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image')); Then How it is working if image is not being uploded.

Comment: That was it, damn. The ! at `if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))` should not be there. It works now Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should do it like this

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
}
else
{
$file_name=$this->upload->file_name;
$this->create_thumb($file_name);
}
```

Then In your controller make this function create_thum

```
function create_thumb($file_name)
     {
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = './uploads/restaurants/restaurants/'.$file_name;  
        $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $config['width'] = 78;
        $config['height'] = 78;
        $config['new_image'] = './uploads/restaurants/restaurants/thumbs/'.$file_name;
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
        {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        }
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = './uploads/restaurants/restaurants/'.$file_name;  
        $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $config['width'] = 304;
        $config['height'] = 251;
        $config['new_image'] = './uploads/restaurants/restaurants/thumbs_big/'.$file_name;
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
        {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        }

        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = './uploads/restaurants/restaurants/'.$file_name;  
        $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $config['width'] = 37;
        $config['height'] = 37;
        $config['new_image'] = './uploads/restaurants/restaurants/thumbs_small/'.$file_name;
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
        {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        }

        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = './uploads/restaurants/restaurants/'.$file_name;  
        $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $config['width'] = 108;
        $config['height'] = 108;
        $config['new_image'] = './uploads/restaurants/restaurants/thumbs_108/'.$file_name;
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
        {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        }
     }
```

Any number of thumbs